# Removing duplicated objects by certain property from json using lodash

Tags: json, lodash

I have a JSON similar to this one:

```
{
    someProperty1: "someProperty1",
    someProperty2: "someProperty2",
    hits: {
        total: 5678,
        hits: [{
            _id: "abcdef123456",
            _source: {
                deviceId: "00001234",
                longitude: -101.51729822158813,
                latitude: 21.008541584014893,
                someOtherProperty: "foo"
            }
        }, {
            _id: "abcdef123456",
            _source: {
                deviceId: "00004321",
                longitude: -101.51729822158823,
                latitude: 21.008541584014893,
                someOtherProperty: "bar"
        }, {
            _id: "abcdef123456",
            _source: {
                deviceId: "00001234",
                longitude: -101.51729822158813,
                latitude: 21.008541584014893,
                someOtherProperty: "foo"
        }
    ]
}
```

This JSON comes from a service that is being updated accordingly to when the device was accessed, so I have a lot of duplicated information since the devices are mainly static all the time.

As you can see, I have 2 registers of `deviceId: 00001234`, what I need to do is get a simpler JSON from where I can get only the `deviceId`, `longitude`, `latitude`, as I need to paint them in a map using Traccar

So, my idea was to filter out the duplicates first using Lodash, and I found some similar problems, where I got some ideas to be able to access some of the JSON's properties.

- [Find a value in an array inside other array with lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415316/find-a-value-in-an-array-inside-other-array-with-lodash) (This gave me the idea on how to access `hits[]` properties.
- [lodash/underscore; compare two objects and remove duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858853/lodash-underscore-compare-two-objects-and-remove-duplicates) (This one gave me a great idea, however they know what their keys are beforehand, I don't, deviceId's are unknown to me until I have the list and everytime I consume the service, the data is changed).

I've tried using some of these script samples:

```
let filteredObject = _.filter(json.hits.hits, function(hit) {
    return _.difference(_.keys(hit._source.deviceId === "00001234")) //Won't work unless I know the deviceId beforehand
})
```

I read there exist `_.first` but this one returns the first N elements from an array.

So, how could I achieve to get the first occurence of `deviceId: "00001234"` along with another one with `deviceId: "00004321"` using Lodash?

Even if I get another object like this one:

```
[{
    deviceId: "00001234",
    longitude: -101.51729822158813,
    latitude: 21.008541584014893,
    someOtherProperty: "foo"
}, {
    deviceId: "00004321",
    longitude: -101.51729822158823,
    latitude: 21.008541584014893,
    someOtherProperty: "bar"
}]
```

Comment: use `reduce` so you have an array with already unique objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a working example using reduce.

```
let unique = x.hits.hits.reduce((acc, item) => {
  let index = _.findIndex(acc, {deviceId: item._source.deviceId});
  if(index === -1) {
    acc.push(item._source);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/W4QfJ/5880/

Comment: I could work, but still getting 100 results, due to some other properties are different inside `_source` like a `timeStamp`. Is there any way to absolutely check for `_source.deviceId`?

Comment: updated my answer to find index searching by deviceId

Comment: Cool exactly what I needed :)